# YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi - Use URL instead of VideoID

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi - 1.2.1, to show Youtube videos in my application. I get the url's from backend and they come in different formats. For example,

```
public static final String DOMAIN_1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

public static final String DOMAIN_2 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

public static final String DOMAIN_3 = "https://youtu.be/";

public static final String DOMAIN_4 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

public static final String DOMAIN_5 = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";
```

All the above urls have VideoID at the end, and I am able to get VideoID and use,

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) activity,
                                            Const.YouTube.API_KEY, videoId, 0,
                                            true, true);
```

to play them. But my problem is, there are also urls such as,

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=15&v=video_id

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id&list=PL1RpYLGwB6WM409EJBVM1MS9bs3httFse&index=1
```

and since there are other characters in it, I couldn't extract the videoID.

Is there a way I can use URL with createVideoIntent() or is there any other way i can use URLs to work with YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.

[EDIT]

If i can't use URL, can someone help me with getting a regex, for extracting videoID from the above Urls?

Comment: You cnt use url to run your vedio in Youtube player. In android world it will only run with vedioId. You have to find a way to extract vedio id

Comment: there is no need for regex ... obviously, you can use [Uri class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

Comment: @Selvin, Can you give me some hint on how I can do that?

Comment: yes, you should start from learning hows the URL is builded, what is the name of the part where the videoid is ... with such information you would be able to find method in Uri class (by reading the docs) which you should use ... this should be easy ...

Comment: hehe ... obviously: `Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id&list=PL1RpYLGwB6WM409EJBVM1MS9bs3httFse&index=1").getQueryParameter("v")` should returns `video_id` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to cut off the rest of the url

Comment: I agree, but what if there are other formats in future. I just want to know, whether i can input the url directly to the api and get the video play.